# Create Windows directory on PATH filled with pointers to executables?

Tags: windows, command-line, path

I'd like to create a personal bin directory on my Windows installation for storing pointers to command-line utilities that I use frequently, like `/usr/local/bin` is for on Linux. I'd like this folder to contain pointers to the actual utilities because I prefer to keep each utility in its own folder, especially when they may need their own DLLs or other executables.

On Linux, if my tool is `~/tools/mytool/mytool` and it prints `Hello World!`, this would be as simple as doing:

```bsh
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
$ ln -s ~/tools/mytool/mytool /usr/local/bin/mytool
$ mytool
Hello World!
```

On Windows, let's say I want my `/usr/local/bin` analogue to be called `C:\bin`, and I want it to contain a pointer to `C:\PortablePrograms\AndroidSDKPlatformTools\adb.exe`. (I'd rather not add `C:\PortablePrograms\AndroidSDKPlatformTools\` to my `PATH` because it has a bunch of other executables I never want to invoke directly.) I tried all of the following:

- Creating a shortcut `adb.lnk` in `C:\bin` pointing at `C:\PortablePrograms\AndroidSDKPlatformTools\adb.exe`, and [adding `.LNK` to my `PATHEXT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921867/6750681)
- `new-item -itemtype symboliclink -path C:\bin\adb.exe -target C:\PortablePrograms\AndroidSDKPlatformTools\adb.exe`
- `new-item -itemtype hardlink -path C:\bin\adb.exe -target C:\PortablePrograms\AndroidSDKPlatformTools\adb.exe`

After each of these, I tried to run `adb`. Powershell never fails the command, but it never does anything. At best, it might be popping up `adb`'s help output into a terminal that instantly closes. With the `hardlink` version, it does launch an `adb` instance, but I only know because I can't remove the hardlink due to it being open in `adb.exe` (probably the `adb` daemon running, but again, I never get any help output.)

---

Is there a way to create a personal bin directory on Windows like I describe above, and populate it with pointers to executables (***not*** copies of executables?) If so, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: First of all, they aren't "pointers".  Not on linux, not on windows.  They are links (hard or soft).  Shortcuts are pointless.  They are only interpreted by the explorer shell.  The utility I would look to is `mklink' but your powershell code will do the trick too.  Let it be known that Windows is not Linux.  In Linux, all of your "dlls" are in known locations and generally can't be loaded from the same directory like windows ones can so simply linking an app (like on Linux) might not work if that app relies on files sitting in the same directory.

Comment: I was using the term "pointers" here as a general term for something that's not a copy, whether it's a hard link, soft link, or perhaps some other Windows feature that I might not have been aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a personal `bin` directory on Windows and populate it with pointers to executables (not copies of executables?)

If all else fails, try using batch files:

1. Create `C:\bin` if it doesn't already exist.
2. Add `C:\bin` to your Windows System Path variable.
3. Restart `Explorer.exe` to refresh your System environment variables. This is typically done by logging out, then logging back in, or restarting your PC.
4. In `C:\bin` create a new text file called `adb.bat`. Note that the title of the batch (`.bat`) file should match whatever command you want to use in the console.
5. In `adb.bat` give the full path of the executable, followed by a space, then `%*`:

   ```
   C:\PortablePrograms\AndroidSDKPlatformTools\adb.exe %*
   ```
6. Open a new command window. Use `adb` to invoke `adb.bat` and, by extension, `adb.exe`.

Repeat steps 4, 5 and 6 for any new executables you wish to add in the future.

Note that it is probably pretty easy to create a script to create these files in a semiautomatic manner, depending on your scripting preferences.

If you care about command windows flashing from invoking `adb.bat`, there may be ways around this.

---

*As an aside, symbolic links have never presented a problem for me. That said, rather than using [mklink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) or PowerShell directly, I use a utility called [Link Shell Extension](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) to create soft links. It makes it extremely easy to pick a link source (`adb.exe`), then drop it another folder (`C:\bin`).*

Comment: Powershell scripts ended up working a little bit better for me. I now have `C:\bin\adb.ps1` containing the text `C:\PortablePrograms\AndroidSDKPlatformTools\adb.exe $args`. The symlink route is still simplest here, but it only seems to work for entirely self-contained tools. The script route is a decent alternative. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got things sorted out. =)